# firefox times out after 2 minutes on ajax-call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, firefox, timeout

I'm trying to make an Ajax call to a page that takes too long to load. I want to wait for the data to load, but firefox times out after two minutes. On the web you'll find the settings that are in the screenshot, but it doesn't help (and I've restarted firefox). How can I make sure firefox (or any other browser) waits for the call to load?

Of course this is only a temporary solution, but I want it to work for now.

[image: screenshot of timeout with settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vikram was right that it was not the browser. It was in Angular. I don't know Angular so I have to hack. I'll show you my hack but don't use it. Consider it as a hint to find a better solution. Also, you probably don't need all the below code changes to have a hack that works.

angular.js

```
function createHttpBackend($browser, createXhr, $browserDefer, callbacks, rawDocument) {
  // TODO(vojta): fix the signature
  return function(method, url, post, callback, headers, timeout,     withCredentials, responseType) {
    // DO NOT COMMIT :) (added line)
    timeout = 5000001;  // added line

    $browser.$$incOutstandingRequestCount();
    url = url || $browser.url();
....
function timeoutRequest() {
  jsonpDone && jsonpDone();
  xhr;// && xhr.abort();
}
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 5000;
}]);
```

But in addition, this proxy to my vagrant machine was causing a timeout:
https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy

web-incoming.js

```
  function timeout(req, res, options) {
    // DO NOT COMMIT
      req.socket.setTimeout(600000);
    //if(options.timeout) {
    //  req.socket.setTimeout(options.timeout);
    //}
```

},

Answer (score 1):

use the timeout, parameter while making ajax call